# instantiating c++ Vector with different objects

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

It's been a couple years since I've touched C++ and I'm having a bit of difficulty with what should be an easy task. I have a `Vector` of `Object` objects. the `Object` constructor takes in X and Y coordinates. For each `Object` in the `Vector` I'd like to instantiate it with psuedo-random coordinates. However, I cannot seem to make the code below work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Image::Image(unsigned nObjects)
{
  srand(2);
  this->nObjects = nObjects;
  objects.resize(nObjects);

  for(int i = 0; i < nObjects; ++i)
  {
      objects.insert(new Object(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()));
  }
}
```

Here's how the vector is instantiated in the Image header file:

```
std::vector<Object> objects;
```

Comment: Show the definition of `objects`. Also your coordinates won't be random if you reseed `rand` every time you call the function.

Comment: Not `Object`, `objects`, the `vector` itself.

Comment: ok, I've made the edit

Comment: Try using std::vector<Object>* objects=new vector<Object>();

Comment: @Wajahat hmm, but I don't have a default constructor for my `Object`, the only constructor I have takes these 4 arguments. By the way, see you around campus, undergrad at SBU here.

Comment: See you too. Why should the default constructor matter anyway?

Comment: nvm, it shouldn't. I didn't read the bracket locations properly

Comment: However, when I do both of these, it doesn't like it: `objects->resize(nObjects);` and `objects.resize(nObjects);`

Comment: It tells me that I'm missing a default constructor when I try to resize. I can overload it with ` objects->resize(nObjects, Object(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()));`, but I'm not sure if that's gonna create unique objects with different values in each of them.

Comment: Just for confirmation, the objects do indeed have the same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objects.reserve(nObjects);
for(int i = 0; i < nObjects; ++i)
    objects.emplace_back(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand());
```

note that you cant both `resize` and do `push_back` or `emplace_back`

Comment: `emplace_back` is a great choice here.

Answer (score 2):

`new` returns a pointer, you have a vector of `Object` values, not pointers to `Object`. You don't need to allocate your `Object`s explicitly on the heap (unless you will be using `Object` polymorphically), add items to the `vector` with

```
objects.push_back(Object(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()));
```

If `objects` is meant to be a collection of derived instances you will need to use something like the following

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects;
```

and add items with

```
objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Some_derived_class>(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand()));
```

(if your library supports `make_unique`, otherwise [roll your own](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/)).

If your library doesn't support `unique_ptr` then update to something that does.

Comment: hmm, I'm using the most recent g++ compiler and it doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: @audiFanatic compile with `-std=c++1y` or `-std=c++11`

Comment: @audiFanatic As long as they use VS 2010 or newer, yes. `make_unique` was added with 2013, older versions can just copy the 4 line snippet in the link above.

Comment: @audiFanatic Or maybe not, it looks like only VS 2013 supports variadic templates. You can simply use `new Some_derived_class` instead of `make_unique`, but read the link to Herb Sutters page as there are some risks involved exception-wise.

Comment: the `resize` has to be dropped or changed to `reserve`